# How to Separate Result Set of MySql Query By Value of WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get column values from table `project` of rows with a matching foreign key in table `branch`. The below queries will give me all the projects across the subqueries, in essence combining the results. However, I don't want to combine the results. I would prefer a separate list containing the results of each subquery. Is this possible? I haven't had much success finding similar questions, but it seems like this would be useful.

```
select 
DISTINCT project from scanner
WHERE scanid IN 
    (select id
     FROM branch 
     WHERE name = 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights')
OR scanid IN
    (select id
     FROM branch 
     WHERE name = 'aPPLES2.aPPLES')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` so you can include the name in the results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.project, b.name
FROM scanner AS s
JOIN branch AS b ON s.scanid = b.id
WHERE b.name IN ('Microsoft.ApplicationInsights', 'aPPLES2.aPPLES')
ORDER BY b.name, s.project
```